# Raspberry Pi 4 shutdown with no Power LED (red) and no ACT LED (green)

Tags: config.txt, shutdown

I've recently modified my boot/config.txt to include the following lines:

```
dtoverlay=gpio-poweroff,gpiopin=9,active_low=n
dtoverlay=gpio-poweroff,gpiopin=10,active_low=n
```

This works exactly how I wanted, but I noticed that the ACT-LED doesn't blink 4x during the shutdown sequence and the POWER-LED doesn't stay on after shutdown. Does this mean that the raspberry pi didn't shut down properly?

Comment: please describe what problem you are having

Comment: Raspberry pi normally shuts down with the ACT-LED (green) blinking 4-5 times and the POWER-LED (red) stays solid until you remove the 5V power source. After modifying my config.txt, I noticed that neither green nor red LEDs are on during shutdown (power is still connected). I am concerned that me modifying the config.txt file might somehow cause the RPI's power to turn off prematurely and possibly lead to corrupt SD card over time. Is my fear correct?

Comment: *Raspberry pi normally shuts down with the ACT-LED (green) blinking 4-5 times* ... if by "4-5 times" you mean 10 times, then you're correct

Comment: My mistake, yes it does normally blink 10 times. Again, after modifying my boot/config.txt, none of this happens and both LEDs are not on during the shutdown sequence. Is this healthy for the SD card?